# Make List to String Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to make list data to string.
My list data like this :

```
[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
```

I want to convert to string like this :

```
"[data1] [data2] [data3]"
```

I try to use join like this :

```
data=[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
list=" ".join(data)
```

But get error like this :

```
  string= " ".join(data)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you aware that you have nested lists (a list that contains lists that contain strings), not a simple list of strings?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I get the list from read CSV File and get that format.

Comment: That's fine. Are you aware that `data` does not contain strings? In fact, it contains lists. You can `join` strings, but not lists. Try another approach with that fact in mind.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you help me with the simple code? Sorry, I'm newbie in Python programming

Comment: @ImamAbdulMahmudi Can there be more than one element in the sublist? If so, how do you want to handle that?

Comment: @AnandSKumar No, It's only one element in sublist

Comment: @ImamAbdulMahmudi Always mention python version which you are using, it will help others to quickly check for solution specific to problem.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 can you help give solution to delete row in CSV file every I done read it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how closely you want the output to conform to your sample, you have a few options, show here in ascending order of complexity:

```
>>> data=[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
>>> str(data)
"[['data1'], ['data2'], ['data3']]"
>>> ' '.join(map(str, data))
"['data1'] ['data2'] ['data3']"
>>> ' '.join(map(str, data)).replace("'", '')
'[data1] [data2] [data3]'
```

Keep in mind that, if your given sample of `data` doesn't match your actual data, these methods may or may not produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
data=[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
t =  map(lambda x : str(x), data)
print(" ".join(t))
```

Live demo - https://repl.it/BOaS

Comment: Why the `lambda x : str(x)` rather than just `str`?

Comment: Oh yeah. You are right. Was trying different things, so forgot to take them out.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x , the elements of the iterable for `str.join()` has to be a string .

The error you are getting - `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found` - is because the elements of the list you pass to `str.join()` is list (as `data` is a list of lists).

If you only have a single element per sublist, you can simply do -

```
" ".join(['[{}]'.format(x[0]) for x in data])
```

Demo -

```
>>> data=[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
>>> " ".join(['[{}]'.format(x[0]) for x in data])
'[data1] [data2] [data3]'
```

---

If the sublists can have multiple elements and in your output you want those multiple elements separated by a `,` . You can use a list comprehension inside `str.join()` to create a list of strings as you want. Example -

```
" ".join(['[{}]'.format(','.join(x)) for x in data])
```

For some other delimiter other than `','` , use that in - `'<delimiter>'.join(x)` .

Demo -

```
>>> data=[['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]
>>> " ".join(['[{}]'.format(','.join(x)) for x in data])
'[data1] [data2] [data3]'
```

For multiple elements in sublist -

```
>>> data=[['data1','data1.1'],['data2'],['data3','data3.1']]
>>> " ".join(['[{}]'.format(','.join(x)) for x in data])
'[data1,data1.1] [data2] [data3,data3.1]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> l = [['data1'], ['data2'], ['data3']]
>>> s = ""
>>> for i in l:
        s+= re.sub(r"\'", "", str(i))
>>> s
'[data1][data2][data3]'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
data = [['data1'], ['data2'], ['data3']]
result = " ".join('[' + a[0] + ']' for a in data)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
In [13]: a = [['data1'],['data2'],['data3']]

In [14]: import json

In [15]: temp = " ".join([json.dumps(x) for x in a]).replace("\"", "")

In [16]: temp
Out[16]: '[data1] [data2] [data3]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This can also be achieved by "Reduce":

```
from functools import reduce
data = [['data1'], ['data2'], ['data3']]
print(list(reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, data)))
```

output: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']