# convert list to string using python reduce()

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert the list of input words ['hdjk', 'salsap', 'sherpa'] to output: 'hdjk salsap sherpa' using the reduce()

Here is the code I am trying to work on:

```
from functools import reduce
input_list =  ['hdjk', 'salsap', 'sherpa']
list(reduce(lambda x,y: x+" "+y, input_list)) # This gives irrelevant output
```

I have also tried this:

```
xinpl = [x.split() for x in input_list]
list(reduce(lambda x,y: x+" "+y, xinpl))
```

This code joins all the elements in the input_list and it works for me

```
print(" ".join(input_list))
```

I looked at other similar threads and been trying this a lot:
[Make List to String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006454/make-list-to-string-python/51691423#51691423)

I am still a learner. Gurus can your please help?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want reduce and not `" ".join`?

Comment: Remove the `list` in `list(reduce(...))` and it works.

Comment: nevermind, I found the answer:

Comment: @ StardustGogeta, thanks it worked. :-)

Comment: @IndPythCoder You're welcome! In that case, please accept the answer if you would like to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @coldspeed, Since I am still a learner I was exploring and trying other ways of achieving the same output through different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reduce` part of the code is working just fine. The only problem is that it is returning a string, which is then converted to a list. Simply remove the `list` in `list(reduce(...))` and it works as expected.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> input_list =  ['hdjk', 'salsap', 'sherpa']
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+" "+y, input_list)
'hdjk salsap sherpa'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = ['All','you','have','to','fear','is','fear','itself']

from functools import reduce

string1 = str(reduce(lambda x,y: x + " " +y, input_list))

print(string1)
```

Comment: consider adding an explanation to your code so that it will help the OP?